# Can't use variables as key, value for mongoose .find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose 5.11.4 and trying to find documents. On the official docs they say

```
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i })
```

I wanna know how to use variables for "name" & "john" and get the exact thing done. this is an API that I'm working on. filter (name) and the value (john) gonna decide by the frontend user. We should search for a given field using the value. Any suggestions?

```
let filter = req.params.filter
let value = req.params.value

MyModel.find({ filter : /value/i })
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegExp object to convert the value to a regular expression.

```
let regex = new RegExp(`${value}`,'options');
```

Now you can use it on mongoose query.

```
model.find({name:regex});
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked : )

let filter = req.params.filter
let value = req.params.value

const filterParam = {}

filterParam[filter] = { $regex: `.*${value}.*` }

const suppliers = await Supplier.find(filterParam)